# I want to verify entered password in using react and ant.design (antd)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I have two fields, password and verify password. I would like to validate that the typed password in the "verify password" field is the same as the one entered in the password field. I am using antd framework. Here is my code piece.

```
 <Row gutter={25} type="flex">
                    <Col xs={24} sm={12}>
                        <h4>Password</h4>
                        <FieldDecorator
                            form={this.props.form}
                            name={"Password"}
                            rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please add a password' },
                            { min: 8, message: 'Password must have a minimum length of 8' },
                            {
                                pattern: new RegExp('^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$'),
                                message: 'Password must contain at least one lowercase letter, uppercase letter, number, and special character'
                            }]}
                        >
                            <Input type="password" size="large" placeholder="********" />
                        </FieldDecorator>
                    </Col>
                    <Col xs={24} sm={12}>
                        <h4>Verify Password</h4>
                        <FieldDecorator
                            form={this.props.form}
                            name={"VerifyPassword"}
                            rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please verify your password' }]}
                        >
                            <Input type="password" size="large" placeholder="********" />
                        </FieldDecorator>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
```

I know there is a validator option that I can use, but I am not sure how to use it in this case. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there is an example in antd.design site:

https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-register